# Import Excel Spreadsheet Into Access

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2013, excel-2013

I have a unique requirement in which I need to import an Excel spreadsheet into Access.  Why it is unique is the fact, that it can be **either** an .xls or an .xlsx Which is why I went the route of the syntax below.  The issue that I am running into is that if the header for column A is not exactly chintook then an error is presented.

Is there a better more efficient way of importing a spreadsheet whether it be .xlsx or .xls into Access 2013?  If the spreadsheet has multiple columns, I ONLY want to import column A, and the column should be a text data type.

```
CreateTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE [TestImport] (FieldPK COUNTER CONSTRAINT PrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY, Chintook TEXT);"
db.Execute CreateTableSQL

'Creating a file selector for .xls or .xlsx files
Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)

With f
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please Select the Excel File To Import"
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"

    If .Show = True Then
        For i = 1 To f.SelectedItems.Count
            'Getting file name selected
            selectedfile = f.SelectedItems(i)
            'Pulling out file extension to use proper import type
            ExtFind = Right(selectedfile, Len(selectedfile) - InStrRev(selectedfile, "."))
            If ExtFind = "xls" Then
                param = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9
            ElseIf ExtFind = "xlsx" Then
                param = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12
            End If
            'Importing spreadsheet into table
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, param, "TestImport", selectedfile, True
         Next i

    Else
        'Messagebox to show that the user clicked out of the import box
        MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
    End If

End With
```

**EDIT**
Or is there a way to import using my current methodology above, but ignore the 1st row of the spreadsheet (header row), so that regardless of what the end user names column A, the outcome is still a successful import?

Comment: something like `currentdb.execute "SELECT XL1.* into [MyNewTable] FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=No; Database=C:\TESTING.xlsx].[Sheet1$a1:a1000] AS XL1"`  or `INSERT INTO [MyTable] SELECT XL1.* FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes; Database=C:\TESTING.xlsx].[Sheet1$a3:a1000] AS XL1`  I've not properly tested, but will do in a bit.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav -> the last row would differe, and may/may not exceed 1000 rows.  Is there a way to dynamically capture the last row?

Comment: That's a different question, :) but `.end(xlDown)` would be a good start